# IBM Maximo - Go To Custom Application (With Where Clause Provided)

Tags: parameters, websphere, integration, maximo

I am working on a Maximo application for our business, and one of their requirements is to keep track of staff that have been offered a shift. If there are 10 staff members, they would need to cycle through this list (ordered by seniority) when offering shifts. In order to keep track of who has been offered a shift, they need to interact with this list somehow.

Also, depending on what shift is being back-filled in the application, the list of eligible staff varies... so a solution also needs to take that into account.

I typically use table domains and lookup lists when a user needs to select from a list of certain staff, however this requirement adds the challenge of updating this list as they look through it.

How can I solve this? As far as I know, lookup lists in Maximo don't allow one to make changes to the records that are being listed...

**One Potential Solution:** I was hoping to design a very simple call-tracking application based on the PERSON table, but if I use another application for this, I need to:

A) Pass certain filter criteria to the application from the parent application.

B) Return the selected record from the child application to the parent application.

The "Go To ____" menu in Maximo looks like it could work, and allows you to return a value, but again - how do I pass contextual filter criteria to the application they are using to choose the record?

Thank you!

Comment: From what I read of this question, you want the list to be refreshed whenever the user inputs new rows. Have you considered adding a dialog that will behave very similarly to a default lookup and just force a databean.reset() afterwards?
That way in the same place users can be able to add new data, and upon successful save, have that data affecting the list they're shown

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Crew application where you can assign a crew type, calendar and shift along with a crew work group.  The crew work group is basically just a person group with the "crew work group" checkbox assigned.  The crew work group/person group is made up of people records which have a Hire Date so that may get you part way towards determining seniority in the group (although I guess you would need to consider that a person could be the senior staff member based on hire date but have only joined the crew via an internal transfer last week).  If needed, you could perhaps add a "current role start date" or similar field to Person.

From there it sounds like you may want to look into whether you could add an additional tab to Crews or create a new custom app (and all that goes with that) to allow the user to select a specific crew and a work period from the crew's calendar then display a list of crew members ordered by hire date desc in a sub-table.  The application would then let you record a status for each crew member for that work period to indicate whether the crew member accepted or rejected the shift also controlling validation to ensure the records in this related sub-table were only able to be modified once previous records had their status fields set.  The sub-table could then be queried to determine who accepted the shift for a specific work period and if necessary, also see who rejected the shift before they did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do the proposed solution without customization. If you look up `WebClientSession` in the [Maximo JavaDocs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/javadocs-maximo-asset-management-76), you might start with the `getAppStack()` method to access and load some context from the containing app, if there is one. But I'm not sure this is the right direction. This is getting rather complicated, which can be a sign that the direction is wrong.

Have you investigated creating an app based on something other than PERSON, or just adding a tab to the People app? If you reread your Question, you might see that "Shift" seems to be the subject, not Person. Like adding Labor to a Work Order, you want to add a Person to a Shift.

So, I think the real answer to your question is that you need to go back and keep thinking about what you're trying to do and come up with a better, simpler solution. Such a solution will likely be able to be built without customization, meaning the finished product may even be supportable.